# Handling preference.xml file in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have created a check box preference for the settings of my app.

So whenever I check or uncheck the box, android automatically created myapp_preferences.xml file.  Which is the default work of android.

And here is my question:

I also maintain a separate xml file to maintain the state of this checkbox. So I think there is no need for myapp_preferences.xml file, which is created by android.
Is there any way to **avoid myapp_preferences.xml** file from being created.?

Here is my code:

```
final CheckBoxPreference CheckBoxPreference = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference(rsrc.getString(R.string.settings_checked));
            CheckBoxPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
            {            
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newPreference)
                {
                    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Custom_Preference, 0);
                    final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                    Boolean newBoolPreference = (Boolean) newPreference;
                    edit.putBoolean(rsrc.getString(R.string.settings_checked), newBoolPreference);
                    edit.commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Whenever I check or uncheck this box, android automatically created its own preference xml file.  I don't want this action.

Comment: Why do you want to maintain the state of this checkbox when android already does it? You should get rid of your file rather than myapp_preferences.xml

Comment: It is must to create my custom preference xml file for other purpose. Sorry, I cannot avoid this.

Comment: Post some code. How you generate your XML file

Comment: Code added. @MadhurAhuja

Comment: If you use standard API `SharedPreferences` (which is always backed by xml file) you can't avoid file creation. Just use your own api to write to your own xml preferences file.

Comment: @CHAKRAVARTHI why don't you make your own xml file containing the `CheckBox` then on check/uncheck events save the changes in `SharedPreference` and then use it wherever you want?

Comment: I am doing these all from my own checkbox layout file.  But android creates its own preference.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

In your `PreferenceActivity` , add this code:

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                PreferenceManager prefMgr = getPreferenceManager();
                prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesName("your custom filename");
                prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

                this.appPreferences.sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

        }
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what I need.